# Как мне выровнять текст в теге <p>?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Есть файл `index.html`  и `index.css`
Как я могу выровнять текст класса `description`, чтобы он переходил на новую строку автоматически?

И какие ошибки с CSS я допустил?

```css
    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .navbar a{
        font: Arial, Sens-Serif;
        font-size: 22px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight: bold;
        display:inline-block;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        text-decoration:none;
        width: 140px;
    }

    .navbar a:hover{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }


    .main-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .article{
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1200px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .article h2{
        padding-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .article:hover{
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

    .date{
        text-align: left;
        padding-top: 40px;
    }

    .description{
        text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
{% extends "navbar.html" %}
{% block title %}Test title index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
<head>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={{ url_for('static', filename='css/index.css') }}>
    <title></title>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
</head>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="main-container">
            <a href="{{article.id}}" class="article">
                <p><h2>{{ article.title }}</h2></p>
                <p class="description">'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'</p>
                <p class="date">{{ article.date }}</p>
                <hr>
            </a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: .description {
    text-align: left;
    word-break: break-all;
}

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов боже, спасибо большое!